# uwsgi broken pipe when running it as systemd service

Tags: python, linux, uwsgi, systemd, conda

I am running a uwsgi/flask python app in a conda virtual environment using python 2.7.11.

I am moving from CentOS 6 to CentOS 7 and want to make use of systemd to run my app as a service. Everything (config and code) works fine if I manually call the start script for my app (`sh start-foo.sh`) but when I try to start it as a systemd service (`sudo systemctl foo start`) it starts the app but then fails right away with the following error:

```
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 8 seconds on interpreter 0x14c38d0 pid: 3504 (default app)
mountpoint  already configured. skip.
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 3504)
emperor_notify_ready()/write(): Broken pipe [core/emperor.c line 2463]
VACUUM: pidfile removed.
```

Here is my systemd Unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /app/foo/bin/start-foo.sh
ExecStop=/bin/bash /app/foo/bin/stop-foo.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Not sure if necessary, but here are my uwsgi emperor and vassal configs:

**Emperor**

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /app/foo/conf/vassals/
daemonize = /var/log/foo/emperor.log
```

**Vassal**

```
[uwsgi]
http-timeout = 500
chdir = /app/foo/scripts
pidfile = /app/foo/scripts/foo.pid
#socket = /app/foo/scripts/foo.soc
http = :8888
wsgi-file = /app/foo/scripts/foo.py
master = 1
processes = %(%k * 2)
threads = 1
module = foo
callable = app
vacuum = True
daemonize = /var/log/foo/uwsgi.log
```

I tried to Google for this issue but can't seem to find anything related. I suspect this has something to do with running uwsgi in a virtual environment and using systemctl to start it. I'm a systemd n00b so let me know if I'm doing something wrong in my Unit file.

This is not a blocker because I can still start/stop my app by executing the scripts manually, but I would like to be able to run it as a service and automatically launch it on startup using systemd.

Comment: Try adding the `Type` and `WorkingDirectory` to the `[Service]` section of the `service` unit file, with `Type=simple` and `WorkingDirectory=/app/foo/bin/`

Comment: @Noelkd, didn't help... same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Systemd.html) at uwsgi's documentation regarding setting up a systemd service fixed the problem.

Here is what I changed:

Removed `daemonize` from both Emperor and Vassal configs.

Took the Unit file from the link above and modified slightly to work with my app

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/app/foo/bin/uwsgi /app/foo/conf/emperor.ini
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```